# Performing a "git push origin master" leaves changes to be committed on origin, why?

Tags: git, ssh

When I push my master branch to origin the commit's appear on origin but for some reason the changes remain both committed and un-committed.
What I mean by that is, when I perform a git status on origin the output is
On branch master

```
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
# file 1
# file 2 etc...
```

So I perform a git reset --hard HEAD and all is ok. The commit's are still on the origin/master branch when I perform a git log.

This only occurs on the master branch, if I am on a different branch and perform a git push origin differentbranch the changes are committed and there are no un-committed files.

The setup I have is a dev server which connects to the production server over ssh using authorized keys.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you doing a `git reset --hard HEAD` ?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "when I perform a git status on origin..."

Comment: graveti I'm performing a git reset --hard HEAD because the changes are already comitted so I don't need to keep any changes in the working tree. And what I mean by "when I perform a git status on origin..." is when I am on the production server which origin refers to, and I am on the master branch and I perform a "git status".

Comment: hvd. I'm missing something here, you say the changes were not committed? How is it that I can see there is commit hash in the log for the master branch? When I perform a "git diff #hashofthechange" and a "git diff --cached" the results are the reverse of each other.

Comment: @ShaunHaddrill Sorry, I should've been clearer. It's certainly possible that everything you wanted to commit did get committed. Luckily, it did indeed. Your comment clarifies your question a bit, and shows that the point I was trying to make is something you do understand already (namely that there really are local changes after the fact -- that shouldn't be there), so I'll delete my previous comment.